# Char.ToUpper When There Is No Upper Case Form

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, char, uppercase

Writing methods that convert to/from camelCase and I had a thought - what about when someone using a Unicode character that has no upper case form comes along and runs it through my function? What about if someone passes an already-capitalized `'A'` into `Char.ToUpper`? I checked the reference source and it just leads into a DllImport - I know that the core CLR source is available but I'm not terribly good at navigating it (it's organized poorly in my opinion, but maybe I just don't understand the logic).

What happens when you pass these things into that function? I know I can test that, but are there any cases like these that break? Anything that throws an exception or causes any kind of failure or unexpected behavior? I'd expect that the function would return the original character in any case where it's not valid to convert it to upper, but is that the case?

Comment: I'm not sure with everything, but I ran into a case once where I had a char with no upper and it just returned it unchanged - no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the [Char.ToUpper method documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d723h14(v=vs.110).aspx) under the return value from the method:

> The uppercase equivalent of c, or the unchanged value of c if c is already uppercase, has no uppercase equivalent, or is not alphabetic.

So it won't break, it'll simply return the character you invoked the method on, unchanged.

Comment: I moused over the function in VS and expected it to tell me, for some reason totally didn't consider looking at the MSDN docs - tired today but apparently more impaired than I thought! Thank you - I'll leave the question up since there was nothing similar on here and it could help someone else even though it was somewhat silly.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d723h14(v=vs.110).aspx) it returns:

> The uppercase equivalent of c, or the unchanged value of c if c is
>   already uppercase, has no uppercase equivalent, or is not alphabetic.

As an example, calling `ToUpper` on "6" will return "6", as numbers do not have an uppercase.

The MSDN example shows the result of several different transformations:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      char[] chars = { 'e', 'E', '6', ',', 'ж', 'ä' };
      foreach (var ch in chars)
          Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1} {2}", ch, Char.ToUpper(ch),
                            ch == Char.ToUpper(ch) ? "(Same Character)" : "" );
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       e --> E
//       E --> E (Same Character)
//       6 --> 6 (Same Character)
//       , --> , (Same Character)
//       ? --> ?
//       ä --> Ä
```

Comment: Curious that according to that code, 'ж' is not displayable in the comments even though it is displayable in the text above. Perhaps they were editing in a specific codepage and never updated the comments when they changed over.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`char.ToUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d723h14(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Char
>
> The uppercase equivalent of c, or the unchanged value of c if c is already uppercase, has no uppercase equivalent, or is not alphabetic.